# Rails query, I want to part of my query to be a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have this method below.

The problem is that I want to pass in twitter_type as a parameter which changes depending on the calling code.  The code below works but the method "followers" is hard coded.  I want that to be the variable twitter_type.  I have tried various ways but get it to work.

```
def get_change_channel(channel_id, twitter_type)
  base_value = Count.where(created_at: Date.yesterday.beginning_of_day..Date.yesterday.end_of_day)
                  .where(channel_id: channel_id).first.followers
get_current_channel_followers(channel_id) - base_value
```

end

Thanks for any guidance.

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`#public_send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Object.html#method-i-public_send):

```
 def get_change_channel(channel_id, twitter_type)
   base_value = Count.where(created_at: Date.yesterday.beginning_of_day..Date.yesterday.end_of_day)
              .where(channel_id: channel_id).first.public_send(twitter_type)
```

Comment: Brilliant, that worked.  Will google what that actually does now!!

Comment: If the `twitter_type` is passed as a parameter from untrusted source it dangerous to just pass it to `public_send` without checking.